# Service from dependency injection returns null

Tags: .net, .net-core, dependency-injection

In my startup.cs I registered my service:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services){
     ...
     services.AddSingleton<ICompareService, CompareService>();
     services.AddSingleton<IConsumer, Consumer>(); 
     ...
}
```

When I would use this in another file it returns an System.NullReferenceException:

HomeController.cs

```
    private readonly IConsumer _consumer;

    public HomeController(IConsumer consumer)
    {
        _consumer = consumer;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public string Get()
    {
        _consumer.Foo("Bar");

        while (true)
        {
            string messageToPublic = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(messageToPublic);

        }

    }
```

Consumer.cs:

```
public class Consumer
{
    private readonly ICompareService _compareService;

    public Consumer(ICompareService compareService) : this()
    {
        _compareService = compareService;
    }
    
    public async Task<string> Foo(string foo){
        _compareService.RunCompare()
    }     
     

}
```

Why is the _compareService null when I want to use it? Is this setup wrong?

Comment: The question in its current state is incomplete and therefore unclear. Without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that clarifies your specific problem or additional details to highlight ***exactly*** what was done, it will be difficult to reproduce the problem that would allow a better understanding of what is the ***actual*** problem.

Comment: Can you reformat the question so we get a clearer picture of the current problem and what you are **actually** trying to do? See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Answer updated!

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because your DI container cannot correlate Iconsumer interface with Consumer class. You consumer class does not inherit the IConsumer interface.

It should be like below to work:

```
public class Consumer : IConsumer
{
    private readonly ICompareService _compareService;

    public Consumer(ICompareService compareService) : this()
    {
        _compareService = compareService;
    }
    
    public async Task<string> Foo(string foo){
        _compareService.RunCompare()
    }     
}
```

And also add an IConsumer interface

```
public interface IConsumer {
   //functionality to be enforced
}
```

Only then the IConsumer interface would be resolved.

I suppose something similar is happening with ICompareService, but you did not provide sufficient info in your question.

But this is quite basic, I would strongly suggest you do some reading on how depedency injection works [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1)